# Making column names in excel

Tags: excel

I have a table in excel like

```
CITY BIG_xxx BIG_aaa BIG_ggg SMALL_ccc SMALL_rrr SMALL_ddd
```

I want to rename the columns to

```
CITY BIG_1 BIG_2 BIG_3 SMALL_1 SMALL_2 SMALL_3
```

How can I do this when there are a large number of columns with BIG_*** and SMALL_***

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your columns start in A1, then in B2 you can use:

```
=IF(COUNTIF($A1:A1, LEFT(B1, FIND("_", B1)-1) & "*")>0, LEFT(B1, FIND("_", B1)-1) & "_" & COUNTIF($A1:A1, LEFT(B1, FIND("_", B1)-1) & "*") + 1, LEFT(B1, FIND("_", B1)-1) & "_1")
```

And copy across all the column fields.

The real heroes in this function are:

1. `LEFT(B1, FIND("_", B1)-1)` which will get the string before the underscore.
2. `COUNTIF($A1:A1, LEFT(B1, FIND("_", B1)-1) & "*")` Which counts how many columns previous to the column that is being renamed share the same string before the underscore using a COUNTIF() with a wildcard match.

In action:
[image]